# AjaxToolkit ModalPopup, how to dynamically set x and y coordinates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have used Modal Pop-up extender in an image gallery project which shows the actually size of images when somebody click's on thumbnail inside a datalist.

Everything works fine, beside the location on ModalPop-up is appears at the random location on the screen and sometimes push the image off the screen to right side, If I hard code x and y coordinates then the small image appears and extreme right not in sync.

If I click, re-size or change the scroll position then it re positions to the center of the page but not otherwise.

Kindly suggest a work around to either change the scroll bar position as soon as ModalPop-up is shown (using client script), or an CSS property which I can use to set it.

Thanks a lot in advance.